# Convert FileReader.readAsBinaryString to Unicode escaped string

Tags: javascript, unicode, filereader

FileReader.[readAsBinaryString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) returns a UTF-8 encoded binary string. How can I get the data as a series of Unicode escaped sequences (\uxxxx) instead?

Comment: Does anyone know how one could convert the data from bytes to escaped unicode characters?

Comment: please show us a working example, i could not reproduce your desired effect with ajax, all i see is squares, not escape codes. that said, you can get an arraybuffer instead, and if you have a binary response, you can use URL.createObjectURL to turn it into an ajax-able thing, where you can do the above trick.

Answer (score 3):

The `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` is deprecated - instead use [readAsArrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer). This allows you to use one of the two following methods to convert the input string to escaped unicode chars:

## Method 1

This uses the ArrayBuffer and a Uint8Array view on it. In the demo below the buffer is assumed pre-loaded (some dummy data is provided instead).

```js
var buffer = new Uint8Array([0x20, 0xac, 0x2b, 0x08]),  // big-endian format
    pos = 0, txt = "";

// iterate buffer byte-per-byte and build string:
while(pos < buffer.length)
    txt += "\\u" + toString(buffer[pos++]) + toString(buffer[pos++]);

// make sure we end up with two digits (v < 0x10)
function toString(v) {
  var s = v.toString(16); return s.length === 1 ? "0" + s : s
}

out.innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<output id="out"></output>
```

You could have used Uint16Array here instead if the data was in little-endian (on most main stream systems that is), and just convert a single value to string instead of two. Or use a DataView so you can read requesting endianess. This may or may not be slightly faster (the browser will do the byte-swapping, and we read 16-bits in one op, but checks are just consolidated in the toString method):

```js
var data = new Uint8Array([0x20, 0xac, 0x2b, 0x08]),  // big-endian format
    view = new DataView(data.buffer),                 // use a view on the ArrayBuffer
    pos = 0, txt = "";

// iterate buffer byte-per-byte and build string:
while(pos < view.byteLength) {
    txt += "\\u" + toString(view.getUint16(pos, false)); // true = little endian
    pos += 2
};

// make sure we end up with four digits
function toString(v) {
  var s = v.toString(16); 
  return s.length === 3 ? "0" + s : (s.length === 2 ? "00" + s : s)
}

out.innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<output id="out"></output>
```

## Method 2

This uses the new TextDecoder API to parse the input buffer - also here assumed to be an ArrayBuffer.

Then `escape` is used with a replace. This is a quick way of converting, BUT `escape()` is deprecated as well. However, it ain't going anywhere soon so if you feel bold, it may be an option - I'll include it here in any case:

```js
var td = new TextDecoder("utf-16be"),                   // be = big endian, def: le
    buffer = new Uint8Array([0x20, 0xac, 0x2b, 0x08]);  // big-endian format

// assumes data loaded into an ArrayBuffer
var txt = td.decode(buffer);

// escape is deprecated but won't go anywhere for a while:
out.innerHTML = escape(txt).replace(/%/g, "\\");

// or use the same last step as in method 1, just showing an alternative way

//=> "\u20AC\u2B08"
```

```html
<output id="out"></output>
```

**Notes:** You may have noticed I have indicated big-endian for byte order. Typically, big-endian (aka network order) is used when reading files or binary data from network. If the data happens to be in little-endian format, you need to swap byte-order:

For **method 1** you could do:

```
while(pos < buffer.length) {
    txt += "\\u" + toString(buffer[pos+1]) + toString(buffer[pos]);
    pos += 2;
}
```

or just used the Uint16Array with the modified toString method mentioned above.

For **method 2** you can simply specify little-endian version for utf-16:

```
var td = new TextDecoder("utf-16");  // default = little-endian
```

Note that `TextDecoder` is not yet stabilized **[nor supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder#Browser_compatibility)**.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found a solution for you.

On [this site](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) I found an open source project that coverts text into Unicode notation.

I edited the functions that were relevant to your project and created a little function to handle opening files.

```
 /*
Copyright (C) 2007  Richard Ishida ishida@w3.org
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms 
of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either 
version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version as long as you point to 
http://rishida.net/ in your code.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; 
without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  
See the GNU General Public License for more details. http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/

 function dec2hex(textString) {
     return (textString + 0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
 }

 function convertCharStr2Unicode(textString, preserve, pad) {
     // converts a string of characters to U+... notation, separated by space
     // textString: string, the string to convert
     // preserve: string enum [ascii, latin1], a set of characters to not convert
     // pad: boolean, if true, hex numbers lower than 1000 are padded with zeros
     var haut = 0;
     var n = 0;
     var CPstring = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < textString.length; i++) {
         var b = textString.charCodeAt(i);
         if (b < 0 || b > 0xFFFF) {
             CPstring += 'Error in convertChar2CP: byte out of range ' + dec2hex(b) + '!';
         }
         if (haut != 0) {
             if (0xDC00 <= b && b <= 0xDFFF) {
                 CPstring += dec2hex(0x10000 + ((haut - 0xD800) << 10) + (b - 0xDC00)) + ' ';
                 haut = 0;
                 continue;
             } else {
                 CPstring += 'Error in convertChar2CP: surrogate out of range ' + dec2hex(haut) + '!';
                 haut = 0;
             }
         }
         if (0xD800 <= b && b <= 0xDBFF) {
             haut = b;
         } else {
             if (b <= 127 && preserve == 'ascii') {
                 CPstring += textString.charAt(i) + ' ';
             } else if (b <= 255 && preserve == 'latin1') {
                 CPstring += textString.charAt(i) + ' ';
             } else {
                 cp = dec2hex(b);
                 if (pad) {
                     while (cp.length < 4) {
                         cp = '0' + cp;
                     }
                 }
                 CPstring += '\\u' + cp + ' ';
             }
         }
     }
     return CPstring.substring(0, CPstring.length - 1);
 }
```

**Demo (With File Handling and Text Input): http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/btp6zd50/**

Answer (score 2):

This function will escape non-ascii characters and transform unicode back to \uHHHH.

```
function ascii(str) {
  var s = ""

  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    var n = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (n >= 32 && n <= 126) {
      // printable ASCII
      s += str.charAt(i);
    } else {
      // unicode escape everything else
      n = n.toString(16);
      n = "0000".substr(n.length) + n;
      s+= "\\u" + n;
    }
  }
  return s
}
```

You might want to preserve text formatting or encode it to \n, \r, \t.  It could be helpful if the text needs to be edited.

```
var x = "♫\n☆\n⚛\n☯\n⚓\n";
console.log(x);

function ascii(str, formatting, convert) {
  var s = ""
  var TAB = 9, LF = 10, CR = 13;
  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    var n = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (n >= 32 && n <= 126) {
      // printable ASCII
      s += str.charAt(i);
    } else if(formatting === true && (n === TAB || n === LF || n === CR)) {
      if (convert === true) {
        s += n === TAB ? "\\t" : n === LF ? "\\n" : "\\r";
      } else {
        s += str.charAt(i);
      }
    } else {
      // unicode escape everything else
      n = n.toString(16);
      n = "0000".substr(n.length) + n;
      s+= "\\u" + n;
    }
  }
  return s;
}

console.log(ascii(x));
console.log(ascii(x, true));
console.log(ascii(x, true, true));
```

Output:

```
♫
☆
⚛
☯
⚓

\u266b\u000a\u2606\u000a\u269b\u000a\u262f\u000a\u2693\u000a

\u266b
\u2606
\u269b
\u262f
\u2693

\u266b\n\u2606\n\u269b\n\u262f\n\u2693\n
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` is not in 
[W3C File API working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader)

Use `Blob`:

```
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
```

In the following snippet I am getting an image, but you can get any binary file type.

```js
var fileDisplayArea= document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');
var testFrame= document.getElementById('testFrame');

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;  // Take care of vendor prefixes.

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// console.log('has CORS',("withCredentials" in xhr));
xhr.open('GET', 'http://i.imgur.com/Ar1SBEH.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var blob = this.response; // becomes type Blob
    console.log(blob);
    
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    testFrame.src = url;
    
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = function(e) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); // Clean up after yourself.
    };
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
    
    
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

```html
<iframe id="testFrame" src=""></iframe>
<div id="fileDisplayArea"></div>
```